# Facebook Intent share doesnt show Activity result on share click

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-intent

I applied a facebook share on my app which of course includes a login but the problem is that when I shared a content to facebook the onActivityResult doesn't give any return. Following the facebook share guide [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share) I implemented everything and shares successfully on both with and withouth facebook app installed. the only difference is that I can get the result on webview but not on intent. Here's my code on the activity result:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Log.e("Activity","You wa shock!");

        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new FacebookDialog.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Exception error, Bundle data) {
                Log.e("Activity", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
                boolean didCancel = FacebookDialog.getNativeDialogDidComplete(data);
                String completionGesture = FacebookDialog.getNativeDialogCompletionGesture(data);
                String postId = FacebookDialog.getNativeDialogPostId(data);

                if (didCancel)
                {
                    if (completionGesture == null || FacebookDialog.COMPLETION_GESTURE_CANCEL.equals(completionGesture)){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"CANCELLED",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        // track post
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"POSTED",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"CANCELLED",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

The other part of the code is just a copy paste exactly on what the tutorial have but for this part even the first log I placed doesn't show up even though I already OAuth'd my app and login successfully.

Comment: Check : https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook which provide easily implement facebook in android

Comment: Hi I already got it. In my case it's because I'm doing this code inside a fragment which throws back the Intent result on my MainActivity which holds the fragment. All I did was to export those codes into my MainActivity then just create a public method for click that will implement facebook share. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do

```
shareFacebookDialog.setFragment(this);
```

where "this" is the fragment
to get the callback in the fragment