# Facebook share result not returned

Tags: android, facebook

Inside my fragment I have an OnactiviyResult that contains:

```
uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new FacebookDialog.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Exception error, Bundle data) {
                Log.e("Activity", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
                Log.d("Activity", "Success!");
                boolean isComplete = FacebookDialog.getNativeDialogDidComplete(data);
                String postId = FacebookDialog.getNativeDialogPostId(data);

                if (isComplete) {
                    String completionGesture = FacebookDialog.getNativeDialogCompletionGesture(data);
                    if (completionGesture == null || FacebookDialog.COMPLETION_GESTURE_CANCEL.equals(completionGesture)) {
                        //Show Publish Cancel Toast
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "User canceled facebook post", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    } else {
                        if (postId != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "user published", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            try {
                                ParseObject game = new ParseObject("Deal");
                                game.put("User", user_ID);
                                game.save();
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } finally {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "got" + user_ID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

The problem that It never gets to it. nothing is returned.
Calling it like that:

```
uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialogBuilder.build().present());
```

Now I found out that it is happening because of the fragment in this question:
[Facebook Intent share doesnt show Activity result on share click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25904260/facebook-intent-share-doesnt-show-activity-result-on-share-click/29237070#29237070)

He says "All I did was to export those codes into my MainActivity"
How exactly It should look? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do

```
shareFacebookDialog.setFragment(this);
```

where "this" is the fragment
to get the callback in the fragment

when you get the result in the onActivityResult

you may need to do `resultCode&0xffff`
as some android versions had a bug with this, and changed the requestcode without turning it back